# retrofit error JSONSyntaxException

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I recently decided to use Retrofit Library for android for doing network calls and also GSON for handling JSON. But I keep getting the following Exception and my app crashes.

```
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:383)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
at $Proxy0.getSMS(Native Method)
at package$AsyncTask.doInBackground()
Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:67)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:367)
... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
at retrofit.converter.GsonConverter.fromBody(GsonConverter.java:63)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
... 14 more
```

I used postman to check JSON Response which is

```
{"success":"true",
"message":"We are going to rock you"}
```

My Interface is as follows:

```
public interface CreateHTTPRequest {
public static final String END_POINT1 = "http://baseurl.com";

@POST("/user/usermob")
public NewRes getSMS(@Query(value = "mobile") String mobile);

// This is used as Model for return type
public static class NewRes {
    String success;
    String message;
}
```

I am making Network Request in AsyncTask as follows:

```
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(CreateHTTPRequest.END_POINT1 /*"https://api.github.com"*/)
        .build();

        CreateHTTPRequest request = restAdapter.create(CreateHTTPRequest.class);
        NewRes response = request.getSMS("123456789");
```

I dont understand what could be wrong. I am new to using Retrofit and GSON, so am not able to figure out eveything.

Comment: Do you get any solution?

Comment: I used the debug tool from retrofit. It seemed the json was not received at the server end in expected format. This was asked with earlier version of retrofit 1.7-1.8, I think. Things may have changed, but I remember that enabling debug in retrofit helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Retrofit Callback for your API Call :

```
public interface CreateHTTPRequest {
    public static final String END_POINT1 = "http://baseurl.com";

    @POST("/user/usermob")
    void getSMS(@Query(value = "mobile") String mobile, Callback<NewRes> callback);
}
```

Take out NewRes and make it as a new class :

```
public class NewRes {
    String success;
    String message;
}
```

Change this line `NewRes response = request.getSMS("123456789");` to :

```
final NewRes newRes;
request.getSMS("123456789", new Callback<NewRes>() {

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        //Do Something on Error
    }

    @Override
    public void success(NewRes newResResponse, Response response) {
        newRes=newResResponse;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps, good luck!